# How to check if a TCP port is available with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, tcp

Is there a more elegant way of checking if a TCP port is available with Delphi other than catching a netstat call?

Comment: Available for what? Connecting to it? Listening on it? Or something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you can use Indy's components to do that. For instance a `TIdHTTPServer` will raise an exception if a port is in use when it is being opened.

So basically you could create such component, bind it to `localhost:<yourport>` and if an exception is raised ( catch it and check it ) then the port is probably in use, else it is free.

I guess other indy components can tell if a port is open or not, but I can't look at it right now.

This was just to give you an approach.

Answer (score 7):

@Mattl, if Available means open for you, you can use this code.

```
program CheckTCP_PortOpen;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Winsock; //Windows Sockets API Unit

    function PortTCPIsOpen(dwPort : Word; ipAddressStr:string) : boolean;
    var
      client : sockaddr_in;//sockaddr_in is used by Windows Sockets to specify a local or remote endpoint address
      sock   : Integer;
    begin
        client.sin_family      := AF_INET;
        client.sin_port        := htons(dwPort);//htons converts a u_short from host to TCP/IP network byte order.
        client.sin_addr.s_addr := inet_addr(PChar(ipAddressStr)); //the inet_addr function converts a string containing an IPv4 dotted-decimal address into a proper address for the IN_ADDR structure.
        sock  :=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);//The socket function creates a socket 
        Result:=connect(sock,client,SizeOf(client))=0;//establishes a connection to a specified socket.
    end;

var
  ret    : Integer;
  wsdata : WSAData;
begin
  Writeln('Init WinSock');
  ret := WSAStartup($0002, wsdata);//initiates use of the Winsock
  if ret<>0 then exit;
  try
    Writeln('Description : '+wsData.szDescription);
    Writeln('Status      : '+wsData.szSystemStatus);

    if PortTCPIsOpen(80,'127.0.0.1') then
    Writeln('Open')
    else
    Writeln('Close');

  finally
  WSACleanup; //terminates use of the Winsock
  end;

  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: I tried it and It works, but it's much slower than the 'bind a port and test if it fails' approach :)

Answer (score 6):

[netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) information can be retrieved by calling the [GetTcpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366026%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [GetUdpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366033%28VS.85%29.aspx) functions in the IP Helper API, or IPHLPAPI.DLL.  For more information on calling the IPHLPAPI.DLL from Delphi, check out this [Network traffic monitor](http://delphi.about.com/od/fullcodeprojects/l/aa112903a.htm).  There are some [wrappers](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fidE47BDA7E986603E83E5266F72CC1ADDDAADF3EC9.aspx?s=socket) for it too, and it is part of [JEDI API Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/files/JEDI%20Windows%20API/).

I wrote a Delphi version of NetStat long ago, but have since lost the source code.  Those resources should get you started though.

Comment: Looks like the "Network traffic Monitor" link is broken and so is the 'wrappers" link.

Answer (score 4):

The following code from [Synapse](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php) works very well:

```
uses
  blcksock;

function PortAvailable(Port:STring):boolean;
var
  svr : TTCPBlockSocket;
begin
  svr := TTCPBlockSocket.Create;
  try
    svr.Bind('0.0.0.0',Port);
    svr.Listen;
    result := svr.LastError = 0;
    Svr.CloseSocket;
  finally
    svr.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using an [Indy.Sockets v10](https://www.indyproject.org/about/) `TIdTCPServer` component:

```pascal
function TExample.IsTCPPortAvailable(const APort: Word): Boolean;
var
  LTCPServer: TIdTCPServer;
  LBinding: TIdSocketHandle;
begin
  Result := True;

  LTCPServer := TIdTCPServer.Create;
  try
    try
      with LTCPServer do
      begin
        DefaultPort   := APort;
        LBinding      := Bindings.Add;
        LBinding.IP   := '127.0.0.1';
        LBinding.Port := APort;
        OnExecute     := TCPServerExecute;
        Active        := True;
      end;
    finally
      LTCPServer.Free;
    end;
  except on EIdCouldNotBindSocket do
    Result := False;
  end;
end;

procedure TExample.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Silver's example above, and since in many cases you want to find an available port rather than just verifying that a given port is in use:

```
uses
  //Indy V10
  IdContext,
  IdSocketHandle,
  IdTcpServer;

type
  //our port-checking tool
  TPortChk = class(TIdTCPServer)
    procedure OnExec(AContext: TIdContext);
  end;

procedure TPortChk.OnExec(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  //does nothing, but must exist and be hooked
end;

//check a TCP port to see if it's already in use.
//normally used before opening a listener.
function PortAvailable(APort: Word): Boolean;
var
  svr: TPortChk;
  bnd: TIdSocketHandle;
begin
  //assume our port is available
  Result := True;
  //create our checking object
  svr := TPortChk.Create;
  try
    //set the execute event
    svr.OnExecute := svr.OnExec;
    //loop looking for an available port
    try
      //set up the binding for our local system and the
      //port in question
      bnd := svr.Bindings.Add;
      bnd.IP := '127.0.0.1';
      bnd.Port := APort;
      //try to bind.  This will throw an EIdCouldNotBindSocket
      //exception if the port is already in use.
      svr.Active := True;
      //if we get here, the port is *currently* available.
      //close the server and bail
      svr.Active := False;
      Exit;
    except
      //whoops, port's in use (or some related failure)
      Result := False;
    end;
  finally
    svr.Free;
  end;
end;

//search a range of ports for the first available
function FindAvailablePort(First, Count: Word): Word;
var
  svr: TPortChk;
  bnd: TIdSocketHandle;
begin
  //assume our initial port is available
  Result := First;
  //create our checking object
  svr := TPortChk.Create;
  try
    //set the execute event
    svr.OnExecute := svr.OnExec;
    //loop looking for an available port
    while (Result - First) < Count do begin
      try
        //set up the binding for our local system and the
        //port in question
        bnd := svr.Bindings.Add;
        bnd.IP := '127.0.0.1';
        bnd.Port := Result;
        //try to bind.  This will throw an EIdCouldNotBindSocket
        //exception if the port is already in use.
        svr.Active := True;
        //if we get here, we found our available port, so kill the
        //server and bail
        svr.Active := False;
        Exit;
      except
        Inc(Result);
        svr.Bindings.Clear;
      end;
    end;
    //if we get here, all of our possible ports are in use,
    //so return $FFFF to indicate that no port is available
    Result := $FFFF;
  finally
    svr.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Loving that people are still answering a ten year old question! Go Delphi!